# Running the same Databricks Python Notebook concurrently

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, databricks

I am running the same notebook three times in parallel using the code below:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

def notebook1_function(country, days):   
         dbutils.notebook.run(path = "/pathtonotebook1/notebook1", \
                              timeout_seconds = 300, \
                              arguments = {"Country":country, "Days":days})

countries = ['US','Canada','UK'] 
days = [2] * len(countries) 
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:   
         results = executor.map(notebook1_function, countries, days)
```

Each time, I am passing different value for 'country' and 2 for 'days'. Inside notebook1 I have df1.
I want to know the following:

1. How to append all the df1's from the three concurrent runs into a single dataframe.
2. How to get the status [Success/Failure] of each run after completion.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `dbutils.notebook.run` (so-called [Notebook workflows](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html)), the notebook is executed as a separate job, and caller of the notebook that doesn't share anything with it - all communication happens via parameters that you're passing to the notebook, and notebook may return only string value specified via call to `dbutils.notebook.exit`.  So your code doesn't have access to the `df1` inside the notebook that you're calling.

Usually, if you're using such notebook workflow, then you need to somehow persist the content of the `df1` from the called notebook into some table, and then read that content from caller notebook.

Another possibility, is to extract the code from the called notebook into the function that will receive arguments, and will return the dataframe, include that notebook via `%run`, call the function with different arguments, and combine results using the `union`.  Something like this:

Notebook 1 (called):

```py
def my_function(country, days):
  # do something
  return dataframe
```

Caller notebook:

```py
%run "./Notebook 1"

df_us = my_function('US', 10)
df_canada = my_function('Canada', 10)
df_uk = my_function('UK', 10)

df_all = df_us.union(df_canada).union(df_uk)
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex for the information. Unfortunately, '%run' will run in execute in series thus slowly down considerably. My final question is in the code above, that information is stored in "results" and how can I access it?

Comment: the `%run` is just execute the notebook - if the notebook only contains function definitions, they will be simply injected into the current Python environment.  And when you'll do your call, and then `union`, then Spark will try to optimize the execution (if your function isn't doing any actions on your own).  If you want to achieve something with `dbutils.notebook.run`, then just force notebooks to write into a separate table, something like: `spark.sql("create table bla-bla-temp"); call notebooks passing that name as parameter to write to, and after execution read data from that temp table

Comment: Hi Alex! Just to be clear here, when I’m forcing notebooks to write to separate tables, if I’m running 30 notebooks, I would need 30 unique tables. Is that correct? If all the notebooks write to the same table what issues should I expect?

Comment: It depends on the table format, and write mode... I personally will go with %run and union... because Spark can it optimize better than separate job if you run notebooks Indepedent

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do this efficiently is to use the same threadpool that you are using and create a new table inside the function that will store the data that you want to load. Make sure that each table has a unique name.

Then, you can union all the tables into one final table at the end.

After the process is done, you can delete the temporary tables for housekeeping purposes.
Instead of returning the df, you can return a dictionary with the table name created and if the run was successfull. You can use those to rerun the failed ones and delete the created tables for those successfull.